# Magento: How to get Order shipping address line 2

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I need to get a second line of Magento order shipping address, currently I am getting information like so:

```
        $this->formatText($order->getBillingAddress()->getData('prefix')),
        $this->formatText($order->getBillingAddress()->getData('firstname')),
        $this->formatText($order->getBillingAddress()->getData('middlename')),
        $this->formatText($order->getBillingAddress()->getData('lastname')),
        $this->formatText($order->getBillingAddress()->getData('suffix')),
        $this->formatText($order->getBillingAddress()->getData('street')),
        $this->formatText($order->getBillingAddress()->getData('city')),
        $this->formatText($order->getBillingAddress()->getData('region')),
        $this->formatText($order->getBillingAddress()->getData('country_id')),
```

All is good, however when customer supplies address line 2, see image below:

[image]

My code does not capture that line, anyone knows how to get address line 2 in Magento?

Answer (score 1):

The question was answered on Magento Stack Exchange, here is the answer if anyone is interested:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/164240/magento-how-to-get-order-shipping-address-line-2